Using CASE in a SELECT WHERE statement
I'm working on an VB application using a SQL database for the first time,
I have a column Removing_Date in on of my tables that has a mixed input data (Text and Dates)
for Example(Never, To be decided later, or exact dates like (21/08/2024))
I'm trying to filter it with date range if it's a date or text if it's text
so here is my code
If CHK_RemovingDate.Checked = True Then

    If CHK_RemovingDateText.Checked = False Then
    
      Sql_Command = "Select * From Main Where CASE IsDate([RemovingDate]) When True Then [RemovingDate] Between '" & RemovingDate1.Value & "' And '" & RemovingDate2.Value & "' End Case"
    
    ElseIf CHK_RemovingDateText.Checked = True Then
    
      Sql_Command = "Select * From Main Where [RemovingDate] LIKE '%" & TXT_RemovingDate_Text.Text & "%'"
    
    End If
    
End If


what is the database at the back-end?

it's a Sql Server database

This is really a troublemaker design decision. You shouldn't have mixed types in a column. Never. Leave the column as Date type add bit columns for each other cases. And learn as fast as you can what is and how to prevent Sql Injection

you have unreachable code due to the IF logic you are using. The first IF allows code to run only if the checkbox is checked, but the next line will never be true. consider re-writing your if/else block

they are 2 different checkboxes (CHK_RemovingDate) and (CHK_RemovingDateText)

Do not build SQL with string concatenation: this is vulnerable to SQL injection! Always parameterise your queries.

Don't use SELECT * in real code: write out the column names in the order that you want them returned. Otherwise, the columns can be returned in any order.

The ElseIf could really simply be an Else because it's either checked or not. Also, it would be simpler to understand by reversing the conditional: If CHK_RemovingDateText.Checked Then ... Else ... End If. And there is no need for = True or = False. Checked is a Boolean already.

All the good advice provided in the comments notwithstanding, one correct syntax for the WHERE clause (for your first query) is:
WHERE TRY_CAST([RemovingDate] as DATE) BETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND 'yyyy-mm-dd'

TRY_CAST attempts to convert the text in the RemovingDate into a date. The result is dependent on the format of the date in text form, and the regional settings of the SQLServer's host. It returns NULL if the text can't be converted  to a valid date (and NULL BETWEEN ... returns false). It would be best if the date in text form follows yyyy-mm-dd format (ISO order of date components). If not, but if the format is consistent, you can use TRY_CONVERT with the correct style parameter.
If you have date in a special form

...not forgetting that BETWEEN is inclusive of the first parameter and exclusive of the second parameter, but somedate >= firstdate AND somedate <= lastdate is often what is intended.

Thank you @tinazmu
I've used TRY_CONVERT as following and it worked
Select * From Main Where TRY_Convert(Date,[RemovingDate],103) Between '" & RemovingDate1.Value & "' And '" & RemovingDate2.Value & "'
